# Angular 2+ (8) Material Snack Bar Displays but is not Dismissing

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I have been pulling my hair out trying to fix this and for the life of me cannot figure it out. I have an application with `"@angular/core": "~8.2.14"` and `"@angular/material": "^8.2.3",` and I have a Snack Bar that I use a global service to call. The dismiss button used to work just fine (around a year ago) but now for some reason has stopped working. This is the code I have:

**notification-snack-bar.component.ts**

```
export class NotificationSnackBarComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_SNACK_BAR_DATA) public data: any,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private notificationService: NotificationService = new NotificationService(),
  ) {
    // message logic here - removed for brevity
  }
  // set the default values
  message = 'Unknown error...';
  action = 'dismiss';

  // close the snack bar
  dismiss(): void {
    // indicate on the service that the error is being closed
    this.notificationService.errorBeingDisplayed = false;
    // dismiss the actual snack bar
    this.snackBar._openedSnackBarRef.dismiss();
  }
}
```

**notification-snack-bar.component.html**

```
<div class="notification-snack-bar-container flex">
  <div>
    <span class="mat-warn-color"
      >An Error Occurred: {{ message }}<br /><span *ngIf="timerCount > 0"
        >Timer: {{ timerCount }}</span
      ></span
    ><br /><span>See the console for the full error.</span>
  </div>
  <button mat-button color="accent" (click)="dismiss()">{{ action }}</button>
</div>
```

**notification.service.ts**

```
export class NotificationService {
  constructor() {}
  // a local flag to keep track of whether or not an error is being shown
  public errorBeingDisplayed = false;
  // the subject to display the error
  private displayErrorSource = new Subject<string>();
  // the observable used to display the error
  public displayError$ = this.displayErrorSource.asObservable();

  /**
   * display any error message that is caught on the page
   *  @params error: string
   */
  //
  displayCaughtError(error: string) {
    // only if there is no error being displayed currently
    if (!this.errorBeingDisplayed) {
      console.log(error);

      // indicate an error is being displayed
      this.errorBeingDisplayed = true;
      // call the .next() method on the source to push the next error to the snack bar
      this.displayErrorSource.next(error);
    }
  }
}
```

**lol-pickem-error.handler.ts**

```
export class LolPickemErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(
    private notificationService: NotificationService = new NotificationService(),
  ) {}
  handleError(error) {
    this.notificationService.displayCaughtError(error.message);
    throw error;
  }
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private snackBar: MatSnackBar,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    public auth: AuthService,
    private zone: NgZone,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notificationService.displayError$.subscribe((error) => {
      // Load the given component into the snack-bar.
      this.zone.run(() => {
        this.snackBar.openFromComponent(NotificationSnackBarComponent, {
          data: {
            message: error,
          },
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**
`providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: LolPickemErrorHandler },]`

The intention is:
* an error is thrown
* the error handler picks up the error and hits the `displayErrorSource.next()` on the `notification.service`
* the `header.component` is subscribed to that, so it in turn creates the snack bar with `.openFromComponent`

and that all works correctly, the snack bar is displayed correctly.

Then, the dismiss button on the `notification-snack-bar.component` does not close the snack bar.

When I put a break point in the browser in the `notification-snack-bar.component.ts` file on the line `this.snackBar._openedSnackBarRef.dismiss();`, I can see that the code comes there and calls that method, but it does not do anything.

While trouble shooting, I have also expanded and tried the following in the `notification-snack-bar-component.ts`:

```
   this.snackBar._openedSnackBarRef.dismiss();
   this.snackBar.dismiss();
   this.snackBarRef.instance.snackBarRef.dismiss();
   this.snackBarRef.dismiss();
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy!

Fyi, this it the repo I am working with (I just artificially threw an error in the Angular code): `https://github.com/blubberbo/LolPickem`

Comment: Your code looks over-complicated and like it's using internals of the snackbar (_openedSnackBarRef). I would check the documentation and start over again: https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/api. Also, what's up with the service reference that looks injected, but is created in the constructor?

Comment: It feels overcomplicated as well! I will start over from the beginning, thank you. Sorry, which service reference are you talking about?

Comment: Glad you worked it out (I would still try to reduce complexity though :) ). The service reference I meant is `private notificationService: NotificationService = new NotificationService()` - normally you would have it marked with `@Injectable`and have angular create it for you using dependency injection.

Comment: Ok, thank you - I will look into that

Answer (score 1):

I did it!

In the `lol-pickem-error.handler.ts`, it used to read just:

```
export class LolPickemErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(
    private notificationService: NotificationService = new NotificationService(),
  ) {}
  handleError(error) {
    this.notificationService.displayCaughtError(error.message);
  }
}
```

and then I added the `throw error;` after calling `this.notificationService. displayCaughtError`, because I still wanted the error to be logged in the console. Needless to say, that was a mistake and caused an a loop that made the snack bar not dismissable!

I changed it to read:

```
 handleError(error) {
    this.notificationService.displayCaughtError(error.message);
    console.error(error);
  }
```

and all is well in the kingdom again!